# File not being uploaded php

Tags: php

UPDATE

I have now solved it, the problem was that I did not have the preciding '/' and I did not have the '/' at the end, here is the final syntax of the folder path: `$folder = '/home/dl/www/uploads/';`

UPDATE

I have updated the code so that is can output some more detailed debugging information, and this is what is output:

```
Warning:  move_uploaded_file(home/dl/www/uploads/test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dl/public_html/file-upload/upload.php on line 9
```

I have the below script which is attempting to upload a selected file to a specified directory on my web server. However, it is not uploading; I have checked that the permissions on the directory is at '777' as per numerous tutorials have suggested, but it is still throwing the 'File is not uploaded' message.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this may not be working?

Thanks!

```
<?php
$folder = "/home/dl/www/uploads";
if (is_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))  {   
    if (move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder.$HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
         Echo "File uploaded";
    } else {
         Echo "File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions";
    };
} else {
     Echo "File is not uploaded.";
}; 
?>
```

The HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which error message are you getting?

Comment: I am just getting a custom error message that I implemented, is there an actual way for the real message to be output?

Comment: Start by using the $_FILES superglobal. Try `var_dump()`-ing $_FILES and add the output to your question.

Comment: Your code has two error messages, "File not moved" and "File is not uploaded". You don't say which of those you're seeing.

Comment: Can we see the HTML of the form?

Comment: Sorry, I have stated which specific message I am getting, and have also stated the HTML form

Comment: @CallumHolden You call your input `file`, but you try and access `filename`....

Comment: Your code is simply assuming uploads never fail. BAD assumption. There's an `['error']` parameter in $_FILES you should be checking before doing ANYTHING with the rest of the upload information.

Comment: @CallumHolden - Thank you. If you're getting the `File is not uploaded` message, it means that your `is_uploaded_file` call is failing - it's not an issue with permissions, because the code isn't getting to that point.

Comment: I have made some updates to the question regarding some new debugging info

Comment: What is the full path for the directory you want to move the file to?

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I have now fixed the issue, please see the update to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$folder = "/home/dl/www/uploads/";
```

instead of

```
$folder = "/home/dl/www/uploads";
```

That is, a slash at the end.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the same error message came up

Comment: I have solved the issue now, your suggestion helped me alot. I realised that I had not put a slash at the end, and had also for some reason removed the slash from the beginning. Thanks for your help! +1